# SQL Server query for next row value where previous row value

Tags: sql-server

This query gives me Event values from 1 to 20 within an hour, how to add to that if a consecutive Event value is >=200 as well?

```
SELECT ID, count(Event) as numberoftimes 
FROM table_name
WHERE Event >=1 and Event <=20
GROUP BY ID, DATEPART(HH, AtHour)
HAVING DATEPART(HH, AtHour) <= 1 
ORDER BY ID desc
```

In this dummy 24h table:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| ID | Event | AtHour |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | 11:00  |
|  1 |     4 | 11:01  |
|  1 |     1 | 11:02  |
|  1 |    20 | 11:03  |
|  1 |   200 | 11:04  |
|  1 |     1 | 13:00  |
|  1 |     1 | 13:05  |
|  1 |     2 | 13:06  |
|  1 |   500 | 13:07  |
|  1 |    39 | 13:10  |
|  1 |    50 | 13:11  |
|  1 |     2 | 13:12  |
+----+-------+--------+
```

I would like to select IDs with Event with values with range between 1 and 20 followed immediately by value greater than or equal to 200 within an hour.

Expected result should be something like that:

```
+----+--------+
| ID | AtHour |
+----+--------+
|  1 |     11 |
|  1 |     13 |
|  2 |     11 |
|  2 |     14 |
|  3 |     09 |
|  3 |     12 |
+----+--------+
```

or just how many times it has happened for unique ID instead of which hour.
Please excuse me I am still rusty with post formatting!

Comment: Check your example table. Seems wrong

Comment: What have you tried so far - please show your current code.

Comment: Can you embed this into your question please

Comment: I don't understand your model; in your table all records have the same ID, so what is the primary key for your table?

Comment: Not exactly, do you mean that ID is a primary key, or not?

Comment: Sorry, I read the question again, ID is not unique across the table. But how is the expected result obtained from your dummy table?

Comment: This is my question too, I managed to make it work for >=1 and <=20 within an hour, my question is how to add to that another evaluation which is - if there are rows with values between 1-20 and row that follows with value of >=200

Comment: Give me a moment, I think I have a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE data (Id INT, Event INT, AtHour SMALLDATETIME);

INSERT data (Id, Event, AtHour) VALUES
(1,1,'2017-03-16 11:00:00'),
(1,4,'2017-03-16 11:01:00'),
(1,1,'2017-03-16 11:02:00'),
(1,20,'2017-03-16 11:03:00'),
(1,200,'2017-03-16 11:04:00'),
(1,1,'2017-03-16 13:00:00'),
(1,1,'2017-03-16 13:05:00'),
(1,2,'2017-03-16 13:06:00'),
(1,500,'2017-03-16 13:07:00'),
(1,39,'2017-03-16 13:10:00')
;

; WITH temp as (
  SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY AtHour)
  , *
  FROM data
)
SELECT a.id, DATEPART(HOUR, a.AtHour) as AtHour, COUNT(*) AS NumOfPairs
FROM temp a JOIN temp b ON a.rownum = b.rownum-1
WHERE a.Event BETWEEN 1 and 20 AND b.Event >= 200 
AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.AtHour, b.AtHour) <= 60
GROUP BY a.id, DATEPART(HOUR, a.AtHour)
;
```

Comment: Did you try my example?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten the "within one hour" part of your question. Can you try again?

Comment: Can you set up a rextester demo with sample data which illustrate the issue?

Comment: It works as I want it with  the sample table you've created, not sure what the problem is with mine, huh

Comment: Show some problematic data!

Comment: I will try hold on, the thing is such data may not exist, but if it does I need to "intercept" it

Comment: There might be many pairs within the same hour, as in (1,10,13:10), (1,200,13:20), (1,5,13:21), (1,300,13:23), and so on. Perhaps you should just use a `distinct` keyword then.

Comment: Possible but not for a particular ID, and the time frame is 24hours. Neverthless I am still trying to make it happen, thanks a lot for the support